# Multiple actors in a use case diagram but all apart of the same general role

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, use-case-diagram

So for a forum in where there's different roles on the forum I've got a question.
Basically there's an moderator/editor role on the forum where the user can edit posts, then there is another moderator/editor role that can edit general information on the forum, such as basic information or images on the front page.

How would I create a use case diagram with two editor actors? Would I separate them and have them one by one or should i let both the roles inherit from a general editor actor?

[image: Example image]

Comment: What should "Being able..." be as a UC? Perfectly noting.

Comment: Again: go and read Bittner/Spence about use cases. This is no "teach me UML" forum. You are stumbling around with very basic things.

Comment: Just an additional remark: Rather than Editor1 and Editor2 name them to as whath they are special in (e.g. 'Regular Editor', 'Admin Editor', etc.)

Comment: Yes I did! Honestly what ended up happening is that I separated them. No point in even having the "general" editor actor. They are all doing different stuff anyways I figured why can't they just be separate then

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The generalization is perfectly ok. The only thing you need to add is a constraint:

[image]

That means that both actors can perform `Some use case`. And the constraint tells that only `Actor2` can do "something special" described in the UC scenario.

Since @bruno was suspicious: if your UC would become something completely different with the constraint you'd model different UCs instead (it's probably the case with yours, but without requirements/context it's impossible to say). However, you can control the flow by attaching a constraint. So the "something special"-part in the flow would be an alternative being skipped for Actor1.

Your "Being able..." are no use cases at all. A use case shows added value. And it's name predicate-subject(-object).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you confuse *actor* and *class* (implementation)

*being able to edit* and *being able to edit information about the forum* are not *use case*, they represent something like a status/right (at implementation level)

Your inheritance between actors offers nothing (because Editor has no corresponding *use case*, your use case is not a use case), you are thinking about inheritance between classes probably.

An actor is a *role*, it is not for instance a person (who can have several roles).

If the *role* to edit a post and the *role* to edit the information concerning the forum are different then you have two different actors, else these actors are a unique actor. For me you have :

[image]

You can if that has a plus value make Administrator inheriting Editor